# VSTS fails to build a ASP.NET project from .NET Core solution

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core solution that has two .NET Core projects and rest of the projects are old .NET projects. It builds fine locally with following entry in Nuget.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="microsoft" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/" />       
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

but fails in VSTS build and seems like that particular project can not use `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Headers` though they are added as reference Here is the trace log:

```
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4475147Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Web.dll" /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\XXX.YYY.Web.Common.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output ..\..\AssemblyInfoBase.cs Constants.cs Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs Helpers\ErrorMessages.cs Interfaces\IRequestMessageProvider.cs Models\AuthState.cs Models\YYYCollectionDto.cs Models\YYYFileInfoDto.cs Models\YYYItemMetadataDto.cs Models\YYYProviderAuthRequestResponseDto.cs Models\YYYProviderDto.cs Models\YYYSearchResultDto.cs Models\YYYThumbnailDto.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "d:\a\_temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4475147Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4705140Z ##[error]src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(75,43): Error CS1061: 'HttpRequestHeaders' does not contain a definition for 'GetCookies' and no extension method 'GetCookies' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestHeaders' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4705140Z Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(75,43): error CS1061: 'HttpRequestHeaders' does not contain a definition for 'GetCookies' and no extension method 'GetCookies' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestHeaders' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\XXX.YYY.Web.Common.csproj]
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4715145Z ##[error]src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(128,21): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CookieHeaderValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4715145Z Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(128,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CookieHeaderValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\XXX.YYY.Web.Common.csproj]
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4715145Z ##[error]src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(126,30): Error CS1061: 'HttpResponseHeaders' does not contain a definition for 'AddCookies' and no extension method 'AddCookies' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponseHeaders' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4715145Z Helpers\AntiCsrfHelper.cs(126,30): error CS1061: 'HttpResponseHeaders' does not contain a definition for 'AddCookies' and no extension method 'AddCookies' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponseHeaders' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\XXX.YYY.Web.Common.csproj]
2017-08-11T16:49:59.4745135Z Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY.Web.Common\XXX.YYY.Web.Common.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-08-11T16:49:59.5605400Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): Error : Cannot find project info for 'd:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY\XXX.YYY.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference.
2017-08-11T16:49:59.5605400Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for 'd:\a\1\s\src\XXX.YYY\XXX.YYY.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference. [d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.csproj]
2017-08-11T16:49:59.5605400Z Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-08-11T16:49:59.6755164Z Project "d:\a\1\s\XXX.YYY.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost.csproj" (21) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-08-11T16:49:59.6755164Z PrepareForBuild:
2017-08-11T16:49:59.6755164Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\".
2017-08-11T16:49:59.6755164Z   Creating directory "obj\Release\net452\win7-x86\".
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2025192Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): Error : Cannot find project info for 'd:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference.
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2025192Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for 'd:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference. [d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost.csproj]
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2025192Z Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\src\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost\XXX.AspNetCore.YYY.TestHost.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2025192Z Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\XXX.YYY.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2045187Z 
2017-08-11T16:50:00.2045187Z Build FAILED
```

Comment: Could you show the detail settings for your build definition? And what's the detail projects type failed the build and could you upload the projects to one drive?

Comment: Removing the existing package and re-installing the System.Net libraries worked fine.